# Validate time is future time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

I want to validate my form such that the time and date entered is not in the past.

I currently have two input boxes, one for the time and one for the date.  They are both validated using `ng-pattern` at the moment. How do I show an error (`ng-invalid`) when both of these input boxes create a date that is in the past?

Note: I can do the actual past vs future calculation (using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)), it is the amalgamation of these input boxes that I do not know how to do. As far as I am aware a `directive` can only work on one element, not two?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="startTime" ng-pattern="/^(?:\d|[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$/">
<input type="text" ng-model="startDate" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/">
```

Comment: You can build a directive that scope to an attribute let say `ng-compare`, and you passed the model property you would like to compare.

Besides you can trie this: https://github.com/ffariasdev/angularjs-compare-to-directive?files=1

Comment: Directives can have as many html elements as you want in the template.

Comment: To build onto what @jme11 said, there is no limit on how much templating you can do in a directive.  Heck, you could make an entire page its own directive if you really wanted to for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [scope.$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch), which you could use to validate both elements together in your controller when either value is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using a different input type such as datetime. This would combine both your startTime and startDate into 1 startDateTime.  You would then get the validation for past or future based on how you set the max and min values.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdatetime-local%5D

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="startDateTime"
  placeholder="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" min="2001-01-01T00:00:00" max="2013-12-31T00:00:00" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up coming up with, its tied fairly heavily to the model, which isn't great but it works.

```
m.directive("futureDate", function () {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$validators.futureDate = function (modelValue) {
                var time = attrs["futureDate"] == "time" ? modelValue : scope.startTime;
                var date = attrs["futureDate"] == "date" ? modelValue : scope.startDate;

                var datetime = moment(date + "T" + time);

                return datetime > moment();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="startTime" data-em-future-date="time">
<input type="text" ng-model="startDate" data-em-future-date="date">
```